# Change dataset entries based on a boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

As part of a wider workflow, I need to perform the following operation: given 3 datasets, (with the same shape): one of them contains only boolean value, and will be referred as the "mask".

Essentially I need a function that changes each entry of the first dataset, using values from the second one, if the corresponding entry in the mask equals 1.

The following function does the job

```
  def swap(a,b,c):
       for i in range(a.shape[0]):
          for j in range(a.shape[1]):
             if c.iloc[i,j]== 1:
                a.iloc[i,j] = b.iloc[i,j]
                return a
```

but I doubt very much this is efficient, to say the least.
For starters, would be certainly best not to iterate over all entries, but just over indices corresponding to 1s in the mask.
Yet, in general,  are there any pandas/numpy functions/implementations I should be considering? I could not find much at all, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.copyto`:

```
a,b,c = np.random.randint([0,10,0,],[10,20,2],[10,3]).T
a
# array([4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7])
b
# array([19, 10, 17, 17, 18, 13, 15, 17, 14, 16])
c
# array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
np.copyto(a,b,where=c.astype(bool))
a
# array([ 4, 10, 17, 17,  3, 13,  3, 17, 14, 16])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `NumPy` will be better:

```
import numpy as np
a = b.values*c.values + a.values*np.logical_not(c.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean array indexing in `numpy`. Here is an simple example:

```py
    A = np.random.randn(5,5)
    B = np.ones((5,5))
    C = np.random.randint(1,size=(5,5))
    A[C==1] = B[C==1]
```